# How can I unit test .NET Core web app while it is running?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2.2 web app `MyApp.Web` running locally using `dotnet run`.

I want to run unit tests in project `MyApp.Web.Tests` at the same time, using `dotnet test`, without having to stop the running web app.

However, I get an error message:

`C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.401\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets(510,5): warning MSB3026: Could not copy "obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyApp.Web.Views.dll" to "<projectdir>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyApp.Web.Views.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file '<projectdir>\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\MyApp.Web.Views.dll' because it is being used by another process.`

Why does .NET Core lock the compiled views? Is there a way to prevent this so I can run the tests?

So far the only solution I have found is to run NCrunch, which copies and builds the projects in a totally separate location. But this requires me running Visual Studio, which I do not always want to do (using Rider instead).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @Marco I know about `dotnet watch run` and `dotnet watch test`, that does not solve my problem. Also, posting links without any comments is not very helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `<RazorCompileOnBuild>false</RazorCompileOnBuild>` to the web project `.csproj` will prevent it from locking the `.Views.dll` file, and allow the project to be rebuilt while it is running, allowing `dotnet test` while the app is running.